# What does Oberst-Gruppenführer Heydrich's armband say?

Tags: tv, the-man-in-the-high-castle

I could make out that Obergruppenführer Smith's armband said something like "New York Corps" but I can't make out what  Oberst-Gruppenführer Heydrich's armband says, maybe it's in German?

What does it say?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a still image from  season 1, episode 9, “Kindness”:

[image]

Enhanced:

[image]

This is indeed German, and it says “Großes Reich,” which means “great reich/realm/empire.” The script is [Fraktur](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fraktur) (blackletter):

[image]

Comment: "Great" as "Greater Nazi Reich" or "great" as in "fantastic"?

Comment: The former. Large.

Comment: Damn. You beat me to it while I was editing. A little later you can also see that these are the only two words on the armband, that *Reich* is followed only by empty space.

Comment: @Hans - I think your screencap was better quality though; http://i.stack.imgur.com/qLfQj.png

Comment: @Valorum Vielen Dank. ;-)